# How would i remove commas when displaying my list and printing its position in the list next to it

Tags: python, list

i would like my code to print when asked only the persons name and what position they are in the list like this:

```
3 jake
5 Dan
```

instead of what my code does:`,,jake,,Dan,,,,`

how would i do remove the commas and print its position in the list on each line  here is my code so far

```
while True:
print ('1 = Add Name ')
print ('2 = Display List ')
print ('3 = Quit \n')

choice = input('What would you like to do: ')
if choice== '1':
    names = ['' for _ in range(9)]
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    position = input('What position in the list would you like to add to: ')
    position = int(position)
    if -1 < position < 9:
        names.insert(position-1, name) 
if choice == '2':
    print(", ".join(names)) 
    continue
if choice == '3':
    print('Program Terminating')
    break
else:
    print('You have entered something invalid ')
    print('There are only 10 names in the list')
    continue
```

Comment: If you're going to post Python code, make sure you reproduce your indentation accurately. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

just perform a loop using `enumerate` and test if `n` is not empty

```
l=["","","Jake","","Dan",""]

for i,n in enumerate(l):
    if n:
        print("{} {}".format(i+1,n))
```

or in one line using a generator comprehension inside `str.join` with a linefeed:

```
print("\n".join("{} {}".format(i+1,n) for i,n in enumerate(l) if n))
```

Comment: damn, I have to type faster :)

Comment: fast answers are sometimes not the best ones. Here it was simple enough so I think everything is covered properly, but don't get discouraged. There's a lot to do on this site.